# Assigning a URL link from an xml document to associate with each image in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

Hi guys I have another question relating to XML and XSLT. I'm Just wondering how I would I go about assigning a URL link from an xml document to associate with each image that is dynamically created. I have displayed each image by using a for-each loop, I have assigned an ID to each image as it filters through, using position() method. So is there a way of assigning the url to the id of each image?? Cant find anyway of doing it. Hope that makes sense. Cheers.

The xslt is as follows.

```
  <xsl:for-each select="cars/car-types">

  <div id = "car_types">
    <h5 id = "Model{position()}"> <xsl:value-of select="name"/> </h5>


 <div id ="imagelist">   
 <img src="{image}" id ="carType{position()}"> //sets the car type with an id of "carType1" and increments.

  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="image"/>

  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
 </div>
 </div>

    </xsl:for-each>
```

XML is as follows, I have really simplified the xml, as it is rather long to post whole thing.

```
<cars>
    <car>
            <name>BMW</name>
            <image>bmw.gif</image>
            <link>http://something</link>
    </car>
    <car>
            <name>Ford</name>
            <image>ford.jpg</image>
            <link>http://something</link>
    </car>
</cars>
```

I have managed to output the images, the next step is to add the link to each car image. (when an image is clicked it takes you to another html page with information for that vehicle.)

Here is the HTML output I expect

```
 </head>
    <body>

    <h5 id="Model1">BMW</h5>
    <div id="imagelist">
    <img src="http://www.bmw.com/_common/highend/templates/individual/experience/mseries/m3coupe/2007/game/image/bmw_m3_coupe_background.jpg id="carType1">

<a href="http://www.bmw.com/" target="_blank"></a> <!--This is the href link I want to add from the XML doc to each image. -->
    </div>

    <h5 id="Model2">Ford</h5>
    <div id="imagelist">
    <img src="http://http://cinemuck.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ford2.jpg" id="carType2">
    <a href="http://www.ford.co.uk/" target="_blank"></a> 
    </div>

    <h5 id="Model3">Volvo</h5>
    <div id="imagelist">
    <img src="http://http://www.heritage-motors.co.uk/userimages/volvo2.jpg" id="carType3">
    <a href="http://www.volvo.com/" target="_blank"></a> 
    </div>

    <h5 id="Model4">Jaguar</h5>
    <div id="imagelist">
    <img src="http://http://autocarimages.com/images/Jaguar%20car%20images/1.jpg" id="carType4">
    <a href="http://www.jaguar.co.uk/" target="_blank"></a> 

    </div>
```

Comment: AFIK it is not possible to use that functions in that way inline in {} as you wrote it. I guess that you need to add a special xsd tag for inserting a dynamic attribute value where you insert the function output with the xsl:value-of tag.

Comment: Could you possible post the XML you are using, and the HTML you wish to output? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I have added the xml and have tried to explain the html I want to output. Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a slight mismatch here, because in your XML you have **car** elements, but in your XSLT, you are looking for **car-types** elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a link to each car image, you can just put an **a** tag foryour **img** tag, and construct the **href** attribute for that in a similar way

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="cars/car">
         <div id="car_types">
            <h5 id="Model{position()}">
               <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </h5>
            <div id="imagelist">
               <img src="{image}" id="carType{position()}"/>
               <a href="{link}" target="_blank">Click here</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note there is no need for the extra `<xsl:attribute name="src">` in your XSLT, when you are already constructing the **src** element for the **img** using Attribute Value Templates.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong mate, your basically assigning the link to the car type position ID? I'm still don't seem to be retrieving the link. This is the closest Ive got with this so far, so really appreciate the help Tim.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "retrieving the link", I am afraid? It may help if you could edit your question to show the HTML you are actually expecting in this instance, because unless you know what HTML you want, you won't actually be write the XSLT to generate it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, meant to say, I am still not able to add a link to each image using the above code.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have added the html output I am expecting. Thanks again.

Comment: Where do the links like "http://www.bmw.com" as they do not appear in your sample XML, or do they come from the **link** elements in your XML? I feel I am missing something here, but I have made an amendment to my question based on this assumption.

Comment: Tim that works perfectly. Really appreciate your help with this. Exactly, the links come from the link elements in my XML.